# Fastest Approach to Save and Read Data from Database in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I am working on an application that needs to save and retrieve data fastly from database.I am using MVC5 razor view with C#.

Scenario may be like there is a post that can be like/unlike by any user and data will be store in database, also user can share that post. For example, facebook. on facebook we like/unlike posts and it is works very fast.

Can any one tell me which database tool**(Sql Server, MySql, Oracle etc)** should I use and which data approach**(Entity framework, Store Procedures, ORM, NoSql etc)** should I use in my scenario ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 5):

Selection of the database completely depends on you.
and it is also dependent on the cost as mysql is free of cost.

You have to identify your requirements and then need to select the database tool.

if you are only considering the speed then you need to read about Entity framework, Store Procedures, ORM, NoSql.

These are the different approaches used for differnt purpose

As Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping) in computer software is a programming technique for converting data between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming languages. This creates, in effect, a “virtual object database” that can be used from within the programming language.

So it completely dendends on your requirement.

But first i will suggest you to read more about these concepts.

thses two links will definitely help you to understand more.

https://kevinlawry.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/why-i-avoid-stored-procedures-and-you-should-too/

http://www.davidwaynebaxter.com/tech/dev/orm-or-sprocs/